# Re-entry into US after 6 months as student

Tags: usa, f1-visas

I am from India. I went to a US university in Spring 2014 for a MS program under a F1 visa. Due to serious health issues, I had to leave US before the start of the program.
I am prepared to go and complete my course this fall. I will receive my I-20 in a week or so.

Will I need to go through the same process with the F1 visa again? I know that under F1 status, I cannot be outside US for more than 5 months. What will happen in my case?